# Reload an html page without refreshing/redirecting it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, reload

I would like to try to find a way to reload my HTML page without making it refresh. For example, I want through a PHP file to reload my 1st page to a second page. Here is my try, but it shows me this message -->
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp64\www\PHP\pesto.php on line 26**

Here is my php file:

```
  <?php
    /* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
    server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
    $link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "mysql3");
    // Check connection
    if($link === false) {
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $user_id =$_POST['user_id'];
    $book_id =$_POST['book_id'];
    $game_id =$_POST['game_id'];
    $site_id =$_POST['site_id'];

    //Attempt insert query execution
    $query = "SELECT site_id FROM components WHERE user_id='$user_id' && book_id='$book_id' && game_id='$game_id' ORDER BY site_id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $result = array();
    $res = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $result[]=$row['site_id'];
    }
    if ($res){
        if($result[0] <20){
           <script>
  $.get("updated-content.html", function(data, status){ $("body").html(data); }).fail(function(e) { alert( "error" +JSON.stringify(e)); })
  </script>
            });
        }
    }

    // while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    //     array_push($result, array($row[0]));}
    // echo json_encode(array($result));

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
```

I don't want to use PHP redirection. I want to make that happen with the usage of jquery. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you please point out which is line 26?

Comment: Welcome. `$.get("updated-content.html",` Is that Javascript inside your PHP?

Comment: Yes, of course @ThumChoonTat. It's this part:  `<script>
  $.get("updated-content.html", function(data, status){ $("body").html(data); }).fail(function(e) { alert( "error" +JSON.stringify(e)); })
  </script>`

Comment: You've to echo your jquery, not mess it with PHP.

Comment: @kerbholz yes. it's javascript. Because i don't want to use php redirect..Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @D.Dimitrov can you show me what command i have to use? Because maybe i don't know how to do it..

Comment: You can use `header()` to redirect to a different page. Or if you want to use `<script>` tags you first need to "end" PHP using `?>`, then your Javascript, then `<?php` to continue PHP code.

Comment: `echo '<script>
  $.get("updated-content.html", function(data, status){ $("body").html(data); }).fail(function(e) { alert( "error" +JSON.stringify(e)); })
  </script>
            });';`

Comment: Take a look at the "Ajax" concept.

Comment: "_I don't want to use PHP redirection._" Why is that? Bad experiences with PHP redirection? What if a user has Javascript disabled?

Comment: You have right about header. But i want to do with the script. Ok, im gonna try right now and i will tell you if i have any problems..

Comment: Check my answer! You can change the page content on the same URL (With page refresh) but without redirects and JS!

Comment: @JasonNathanael i think we are very close to solve this issue. Now it shows me  a blank page with the url `http://127.0.0.1/PHP/pesto.php`

Comment: @D.Dimitrov i did it but it doesn't show me the updated-content.html page. Should i have to use dots or backslashes in front of my file name?

Comment: WOW, EVEN stackoverflow recognizes syntax error, 
   @ echo <script>TL;DR  </script>;   - opening and closing script tag has different color. Impressive isn't it

Comment: @BILALMALIK yes you have right...haha it's the best..

Comment: @JohnnyCage - Yes Indeed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error unexpected syntax clearly explains what the problem is... it does not expect that to be there!
Common fix : Check your semicolon and brackets.
It is obious you MUST use a `"` or `'`.

```
if ($res){
    if($result[0] <20){
    echo '<script>
            $.get("updated-content.html", function(data, status){ $("body").html(data); }).fail(function(e) { alert( "error" +JSON.stringify(e)); })
          </script>';
    }
}
```

Also you should be using prepared statements as your code above is vulnerable to SQL injection. You can learn more by Googling "SQL Injection" and "Prepared Statements PHP".

You can also use PHP to `include` or `require` files based on conditions...
Such as :

```
<?php

if ($res){
    if($result[0] <20){
        include 'updated-content.html';
    }else{
        include 'file.html';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You have syntax error, too.

Comment: Whoops, sorry for that... fixed.

Comment: @JasonNathanael  thank you for your help. Now it doesn;'t show me errors but it doesn;t show me also my updated-content.html page. I have placed this page inside www folder in my wamp directory. Do you know if i have to use some slashes or dots in front of file name?

Comment: @JohnnyCage, hit `F12` on your keyboard and it should open a 'Developer Console'. Go to the `Console` section and look for errors such as `404 Page Not Founded`.

Comment: @JasonNathanael this is cool. Thank you! It shows me this: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at pesto.php:2`

Comment: Okay, is the `$` you wanted is jQuery? is yes then include the jQuery library BEFORE the code above.

Comment: @JasonNathanael i can't believe it!!! It works finally. Thank you so much! Do you want to post your answer in order to give you thumbs up in stackoverflow?

Comment: @JohnnyCage I've posted my answer and you're currently commenting on it. Accept the answer if this solves your problem. Thank you and happy coding :D

Comment: I wish you have anice day. Thank you so much for your helpa again! I was stacked yesterday and i couldn't find a solution to this..